# Powershell Unable to load Private key using New-SelfSignedCertificate

Tags: powershell, openssl

1. I have been trying to create a rootCA and intermediate CA which signs the certs using powershell on Windows 10
2. When I try to check the QA1KeyCARoot.key, I m getting an error unable to load private key.

Question:

1. Is this the right way to extract the key from the pfx file using powershell? The pfx should contain both certificate and private key of rootCA

   $CertRootCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My$RootCAthumbprint -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.pfx -Password $CertRootCAPassword
2. How do I get the chain in pem from the commands?

Thanks

Root CA

```
$RootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=KeyCARootCN,O=Test Organisation, OU=Test RootCA,C=AU'  -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256' -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment,CertSign,DigitalSignature,CRLSign -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider' -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(40) -KeyUsageProperty All -TextExtension @(“2.5.29.19 ={critical} {text}ca=1&pathlength=5”) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$RootCA
$RootCAthumbprint = $RootCA.Thumbprint


$CertRootCAPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String “Test123” -Force –AsPlainText
$CertRootCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\$RootCAthumbprint -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.pfx -Password $CertRootCAPassword

$CertRootCAFileCER = Export-Certificate -Cert $RootCA -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.cer

$CertRootCAFileCER
$CertRootCAPath = 'C:\Users\KeyCARoot.cer'
Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Intermediate CA

```
$InterCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=KeyInterCARootCN,O=Test Organisation, OU=Test InterCA,C=AU' -Signer $RootCA -KeyLength 2048 -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256' -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment,CertSign,DigitalSignature,CRLSign -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider' -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(35) -KeyUsageProperty Sign -TextExtension @(“2.5.29.19 = {critical} {text}ca=1&pathlength=0”) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$InterCAthumbprint = $InterCA.Thumbprint


$CertInterCAPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String “Test123” -Force –AsPlainText
$CertInterCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\$InterCAthumbprint -FilePath C:\Users\KeyInterCARoot.pfx -Password $CertInterCAPassword

$CertInterCAFileCER = Export-Certificate -Cert $InterCA -FilePath C:\Users\KeyInterCARoot.cer

$CertInterCAFileCER
Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\Users\KeyInterCARoot.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

Then

```
openssl pkcs12 -in KeyCARoot.pfx -nocerts -nodes  -passin pass:Test123 | sed -ne "/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p" > KeyCARoot.key
openssl pkcs12 -in KeyInterCARoot.pfx -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:Test123 | sed -ne "/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p" > KeyInterCARoot.key

openssl x509 -inform der -in KeyCARoot.cer -out KeyCARoot.pem
openssl x509 -inform der -in KeyInterCARoot.cer -out KeyInterCARoot.pem
```

Ran the following:

```
openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in KeyCARoot.key
openssl : unable to load Private Key
At line:1 char:1
openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in KeyCARoot.key
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (unable to load Private Key:String) [], RemoteException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
8924:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I have removed the Bag attributes in the .key file
Bag Attributes

```
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: te-3737d2a6-b5dc-4d63-b680-68a42d8080a0
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
....
...
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Where is the `QA1KeyCARoot.key` file supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in my post. Its actually KeyCARoot.key. Will fix my post.      I am assuming $CertRootCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My$RootCAthumbprint -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.pfx -Password $CertRootCAPassword ..... creates the pfx which contains the certificate and private key. Then I can export the private key out using the openssl pkcs12 command. Unfortunately it gives me unable to load private key error

Comment: When exporting the `.key` files, try specifying the OpenSSL `-keyex` option.  If that doesn't help, please indicate your OpenSSL and PowerShell versions being used, as well as your OS platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
1) I tried openssl pkcs12 -in <input.pfx> -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:Test321 -keyex | sed -ne "/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p" > <output.key> - It didnt work
2) Versions:
Windows 10 (VM)
5.1.19041.610
OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
3) I noticed after the sed , and I checked in Notepad++, the encoding is UCS-2 LE BOM, this doesnt look quite right?

Answer (score 0):

Using [my prior answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950180/11609403) to create your Root and Intermediate CA certificates, export the PKCS#12 (.pfx) file as you've done above:

```
$RootCAthumbprint = $RootCA.Thumbprint
$CertRootCAPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Test123' -Force -AsPlainText
$CertRootCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$RootCAthumbprint" -FilePath .\KeyCARoot.pfx -Password $CertRootCAPassword
$CertRootCAFileCER = Export-Certificate -Cert $RootCA -FilePath .\KeyCARoot.cer
$CertRootCAFileCER
$CertRootCAPath = '.\KeyCARoot.cer'
Import-Certificate -FilePath .\KeyCARoot.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

...then extract the unencrypted RSA private key using OpenSSL, like so:

```
& "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\1.1.1h\bin\openssl.exe" pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -in .\KeyCARoot.pfx -out .\KeyCARoot.key -passin pass:Test123
```

Once the unencrypted RSA private key is extracted, you can then call OpenSSL rsa to obtain the modulus:

```
& "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\1.1.1h\bin\openssl.exe" rsa -modulus -noout -in .\KeyCARoot.key
```

...without error, and with bag attributes included!