# How to remove Enhanced Key Usage using New-SelfSignedCertificate

Tags: powershell

After running the following command, the Extended Key Usage / Enhanced Key Usage is showing both client and server authorization, how do I remove this option for Root CAs and Intermediate CAs, as CAs should not have these options. What other parameters should be added into the New-SelfSignedCertificate to remove the option below?
Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)

Windows 10
Power Shell v5
openssl 1.1.1

```
$RootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=KeyCARootCN,O=Test Organisation, OU=Test RootCA,C=AU'  -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256' -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment,CertSign,DigitalSignature,CRLSign -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider' -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(40) -KeyUsageProperty All -TextExtension @(“2.5.29.19 ={critical} {text}ca=1&pathlength=5”) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$RootCA
$RootCAthumbprint = $RootCA.Thumbprint


$CertRootCAPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String “Test123” -Force –AsPlainText
$CertRootCAFilePFX = Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\$RootCAthumbprint -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.pfx -Password $CertRootCAPassword

$CertRootCAFileCER = Export-Certificate -Cert $RootCA -FilePath C:\Users\KeyCARoot.cer

$CertRootCAFileCER
$CertRootCAPath = 'C:\Users\KeyCARoot.cer'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Import-Module PKI

$params = @{
    Type = [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.CertificateType]::Custom
    Subject = 'CN=KeyCARootCN,O=Test Organisation, OU=Test RootCA,C=AU'
    KeyLength = 2048
    KeyAlgorithm = 'RSA'
    HashAlgorithm = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256
    KeyExportPolicy = [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeyExportPolicy]::Exportable
    KeySpec = [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeySpec]::Signature
    KeyUsage = @([Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeyUsage]::CertSign,
        [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeyUsage]::DigitalSignature,
        [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeyUsage]::CRLSign)
    KeyUsageProperty = [Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.KeyUsageProperty]::All
    TextExtension = @('2.5.29.19={critical}{text}ca=1&pathlength=5')
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(40)
    Provider = 'Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0'
    CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
}

$RootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate @params
```

In general, you may have over-specified some options that aren't necessary.  As you can see from above, I simply added a `Custom` certificate type, removed the `KeyEncipherment` and `DataEncipherment` Key Usage options, and swapped-out the CSP provider.  Retaining all the signing options for Key Usage should suffice for Root and Intermediate CA certs.

Optionally, you could add `,'2.5.29.37={text}2.5.29.37.0'` to your `TextExtension` list if you wanted your Enhanced Key Usage to be "Any Purpose".